# How to make `unoconv` to produce exact output on every run?

Tags: linux, documents, file-conversion

I came across the `unoconv` linux utility for converting document formats. I found that unoconv produces different output everytime it is called with same input file.

```
bash$ unoconv -f doc test.html
bash$ md5sum test.doc
5895dee91a64699d04dfdb71c2be780b
bash$ rm test.doc
bash$ unoconv -f doc test.html
bash$ md5sum test.doc
33ec9298ef4c40c50cc4ade7bf1ab93a
```

How to overcome this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could `diff` the results to see what is causing the difference - my guess is a timestamp. Wordprocessor documents can contain functions and fields that are evaluated when "published".

```
$ unoconv -f doc test1.html
$ unoconv -f doc test2.html
$ diff test1.htm test2.html
```